# Losing props state data when reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, redux, mapstatetoprops

Here is the code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
  const sheets = state.firestore.data.sheets;
  const sheet = sheets && sheets[id];
  const rows = sheet.rows;

  return {
    rows: rows,
  };
};

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect(() => ["sheets"]),
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Table);
```

data structure:

```
sheets:[
  filename:'abc.txt',
  rows:[ {somedata} , {somedata} ]
]
```

On loading the page I'm able to load rows, but on reloading I lose the data in state. Here is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined

[errorpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhvFY.jpg)

Comment: Could be that the mapStateToProps function is being called before the redux data is ready, and thus your nested search would trigger that "Cannot read... of undefined" error. Where are you making the request for data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using redux, there is a package to help you persist your data in local storage it is called redux-persist. You will have your state even if refreshing/closing the page

Answer (score 0):

If you think that using redux-persist is overkill for your project, one way could be the following.
In your reducer, you could set the initial state in a way that it looks on the local storage for a specific piece of data.

```
const INIT_STATE = { pieceOfData: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pieceOfData")) }
```

The first time that piece of data is fetched it will be null.
In your reducer than you would have your normal state updates.

```
case SET_DATA: { return {...state, pieceOfData: action.payload } }
```

In your action dispatcher, when you fetch the data write it in the LS and dispatch the corresponding action to update the redux store:

```
localStorage.setItem("pieceOfData", JSON.stringify(pieceOfData));
dispatch({type: SET_DATA, payload: pieceOfData});
```

Whenever you will need to access that data from the redux store:

```
const TestComponent = () => {
    const {pieceOfData} = useSelector((state) => state);
    
    return (
        {/*  Remember to check if pieceOfData is already available  */}
        pieceOfData
        ? <p> { pieceOfData.field } </p>
        : <Loader />
    )
}
```

I wouldn't suggest this approach for big projects; in that case, please take a look at plugins such as redux-persist.